# Disabling tooltip removes page title

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am using Jquery UI's tooltip widget to display help text. I have then added a button to disable the helptext. This is done by using the following when a button is pressed.

```
$(document).tooltip("disable");
```

The problem is when I do this the text in the  tag is removed. By enabling the tooltip again the text comes back.

The problem is When the tooltip is enabled the tab in the browers says: "MyCompany" but when the title is removed when disabling the tooltip it changes the https:// mycompany.com.

Is there something I am missing? How do I avoid the page title from being removed?

Comment: So where's your problem exactly?

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is the tab in the browser displays the title of the page, and when the text I chose is removed it goes back to https:// www.mycompany.com instead.

Comment: I think this is a legit jQuery bug and should be reported.

Comment: @Ayman Using tooltip on $(document) still worked with everything, but just removed the title also. They actually have an example of Jquery's website where they use the document as the selector, so it might be a bug.

Comment: @AsgerJohansen, so I did some research in order to report the bug and discovered that this issue is limited to jQuery versions previous to v2. Your original code should work if you use jQuery 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that using `$(document)` as a selector for tooltips affects the html `<title>` tag. 
The solution is to be more specific with the selector:

```
$('.has-tooltip').tooltip();
```

(add a class - eg:`has-tooltip` - to all the elements that will receive a tooltip).

However, you can use even general selectors, like:

```
$('*').tooltip();
```

or

```
$('body').tooltip();
```

---

**Update**
This issue is limited to jQuery versions **previous to v2**. Using `$(document)` as selector should work fine for **jQuery 2.x**.
(thanks @Ayman Safadi for your research).

Comment: That seemed to do it. I changed all the $(document) tags to $('body) instead. This worked. Thanks